# Redirect to Local IIS server page from Hosted website in javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, .net, iis

I'm having a web application hosted in local IIS machine(Working PC) and also a application hosted in a server. In a scenario where i cant print a report, i need to pass a value to the page which is in Local IIS machine and open the page where i could able to print the report.

Is that possible?

If yes, how to do that?

I have tried like redirecting using the local IP but that doesn't work.

//Code

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     function OpenPopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
         var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
         var top = (screen.height - h) / 4;  // for 25% - divide by 4  |  for 33% - divide by 3
         var targetWin = window.open("Report.aspx?Invoiceno=5555", "Print", 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
     } 
    </script>
```

In the above code the Report.aspx page is in the local IIS server.

Comment: What do you mean by "local IIS machine"? Your working pc?

Comment: @RononDex: Yes, exactly.

Comment: Off top of my head have you tried `var targetWin = window.open("http://localhost/Report.aspx?...`

Comment: Is that an intranet site or has your local IIS also to be available to the internet?

Comment: @Belogix: Super Cool.. That opened my page. But not the print. I'm not sure that the print did not work due to the call from a hosted website or something. Let me check.

Comment: @Belogix: That works fine. But there is no print. Any idea?

Comment: If you run the Report.aspx page from VS does it print okay? If not can you debug it?

Comment: Now its working fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Expanding on my comment you want to use `http://localhost` so:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
   function OpenPopupCenter(pageURL, title, w, h) {
       var left = (screen.width - w) / 2;
       var top = (screen.height - h) / 4;  // for 25% - divide by 4  |  for 33% - divide by 3
       var targetWin = window.open("http://localhost/Report.aspx?Invoiceno=5555", "Print", 'toolbar=no, location=no, directories=no, status=no, menubar=no, scrollbars=no, resizable=no, copyhistory=no, width=' + w + ', height=' + h + ', top=' + top + ', left=' + left);
 } 
</script>
```